# How in the world is this a list if it uses ()?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So in python I have this tuple, or at least it SHOULD be a tuple:

```
    listOfNames = ([(name, 'male') for name in names.words('male.txt')] + [(name, 'female') for name in names.words('female.txt')])
```

Yet when I run type(listOfNames), it returns "list". But why? There are clearly parentheses on the outside. Is this some new convention I am not aware of?

Comment: A singleton tuple needs a trailing comma (e.g. `1,` or `(1, )`. Otherwise it’s just a parenthesized expression.

Answer (score 0):

A single () with no separators passes through whatever is inside it

```py
>>> "something"
'something'
>>> ("something")
'something'
>>> ("something",)
('something',)
```

To make a tuple, you need a trailing comma or to explicitly cast to a tuple `tuple()`

```py
(x)   # just x
(x,)  # tuple containing x
```

If you want to create a tuple directly, you can skip creating the intermediate list, and form a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)

You actually already do this when [forming the list in your question](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but it may come with a different name

```py
[x for x in my_iterable if some_condition(x)]       # list comprehension
(x for x in my_iterable if some_condition(x))       # generator expression
tuple(x for x in my_iterable if some_condition(x))  # tuple from generator
```